# How to save expansion state of org-file?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to setup org-mode so that the expansion state of everything within a file is automatically saved when closing the file or quitting?

The [Org-Mode FAQ](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html) says this is not possible, but maybe someone has a hand-rolled solution.

Comment: I do realize that I'm necroposting, but, here at the end of 2023, this is once again possible, even simple. See [Store and recover expansion state within org mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79658/store-and-recover-expansion-state-within-org-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was wondering the same when I started using emacs.

There is the [initial visibility business](http://orgmode.org/manual/Initial-visibility.html#Initial-visibility), but I presume that you already know about this.

I spent some time looking, but could not find a way to implement this directly. One way to implement this might be to write a custom property and change it when expanding/hiding subtrees, but this would take a lot of effort to write.

That said, after a while I found that it wasn't really much of a deal for me. I use helm/helm-swoop/worp-goto to quickly find things in my file. (Highly reccomended btw), can be downloaded from [melpa](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html)

I also use this function to hide everything except the current header:

```
  (defun org-show-current-heading-tidily ()
      (interactive)
      "Show next entry, keeping other entries closed."
      (if (save-excursion (end-of-line) (outline-invisible-p))
          (progn (org-show-entry) (show-children))
        (outline-back-to-heading)
        (unless (and (bolp) (org-on-heading-p))
          (org-up-heading-safe)
          (hide-subtree)
          (error "Boundary reached"))
        (org-overview)
        (org-reveal t)
        (org-show-entry)
        (show-children)))

  (local-set-key (kbd "C-=") 'org-show-current-heading-tidily)
```

If curious, this is my full .emacs file:
http://paste.fedoraproject.org/184916/14237726/raw/

Comment: I'm glad it helped =]